# Maven - synch "main" folder with "tests" folder

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, maven

I'm just starting to use Maven with my project. All of my production code is of course inside the **main** directory. As I add unit tests to my **tests** directory, is there a way to synchronize the `main` dir with my `tests` dir?

For example, say I add a new package `org.bio.mynewpackage`. I have to go in my **main** folder and add the same package name... this is rather annoying.

Any ideas?

Comment: What IDE are you using? It sounds like the sort of thing that it might be able to do for you. (Maven doesn't care; *it's* job is particularly the production of the contents of the `target` directory so that you can focus on your source…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Groovy Script embedded in a [GMaven plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code) execution. It does exactly what you are asking for.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>mirror-folder-structure</id>
            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>
                            <![CDATA[
static void createShadow(File base, File shadow){
    if(base.exists()&&!shadow.exists())shadow.mkdirs();
    base.eachDir { createShadow(it, new File(shadow, it.name))};
}
createShadow(pom.build.sourceDirectory,pom.build.testSourceDirectory);
                            ]]>
                </source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The problem is: it won't run automatically. I have bound it to the phase `generate-test-sources`, but you can choose any other phase. You will however have to execute that phase manually, e.g. `mvn generate-test-sources`.

If you would however consider using Eclipse with the m2eclipse plugin, m2eclipse lets you define lifecycle phases that it runs automatically when you have saved a file, so that would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get your problem right: usually, by convention, maven will detect all class files in main/java and all class files in test/java. You don't have to declare the package names.

So if you add an new package an classes to "main", they will be compiled and packaged, if you add some new tests to "test", the will be autodiscovered and executed in the test phase.

Comment: Yes sure I understand this. However it sounds logical to keep the same directory structure in "main" as you have in "test". Was just wondering if Maven did this automatically. So for example if you have `org.bio.something.MyApp` in main, you probably want the tests for it located under `org.bio.something.MyAppTest` in the test dir.

Comment: @Luca - but this is not maven's job. Maven is used for building your application (compile, test, package, deploy), not for creating source folders or organizing code.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I would rely on the IDE to do this when I create tests.

Eg:

- I create a new class `org.bio.mynewpackage.MyNewClass` in `main/`.
- Now when I create a test `org.bio.mynewpackage.MyNewClassTest`, the IDE should automatically create the necessary directory tree.

Comment: Alright. I'm not a big IDE fan just yet, I thought Maven had something for this.

Comment: Maven has many purposes, but substituting for an IDE is not one of them.

Comment: @S.P.Floyd - sure of course not, I never said that. But considering that Maven brings directory structure as its main feature, I thought something like this would be built in.

Comment: @Luca I'm sure you could write a plugin to replicate the directory structure in test/ and main/, but what's the point? Also, do your tests always _have_ to have the same package structure as your sources?

Comment: @Here Be Wolves - having the same packages structure is just an extra standard practice that seems logical. If other people are looking at my code they know exactly where to find the tests for a specific package class.

Comment: It's also convenient as it gives the tests access to package-scoped classes and methods.

Comment: @Luca I mean: what you need is an identical _package_ structure, not an identical _directory_ structure. It is just coincidence that both mean the same, but if classes in some package do not have their own unit tests, it would be pointless to have directories for those pakcages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you were looking for something specific regards how maven might help you do this. Still i've always used rsync to match to target folders.

Something along the lines of:
    rsync -Crit ./source ./target

1. where C ignores versioning
   files/folders such as .svn
2. r is recursion i is information output.
3. t is timestamp. i've always put this
   to ensure differences in files are
   based on time stamp.

Add 'n' to run in test mode, it will output what will change rather than actually do it. Always do this first as rsync can totally mess things up if you don't have it right.

You can also add pattern matching rules, either in a file in each directory or once in the command line.

Comment: I think he's only looking for a way to sync directories, not files.

Comment: rsync would do that also. Given i've not used maven extensively, i'm probably almost off topic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any plugin that does this, but it should be pretty easy to write one. It could possibly even be done with some simple Groovy scripting using gmaven-plugin or the like.

Alternatively, this shell command should do what you want:

```
# ! -wholename '*/.*' excludes hidden dirs like .svn
$( cd src/main/java/ && find -type d ! -wholename '*/.*' -exec mkdir -p ../../test/java/{} \; )
```

EDIT:

Here's a [simple Maven plugin](https://gist.github.com/719773) (this plugin sorts entries of eclipse .classpath files by name) that should give you a quick start into Maven plugin development.